# Proper Use of a Mud Ring?

Tags: electrical, drywall, laundry, rough-in, remodel

Getting ready to hang the drywall in the garage, it's 5/8" - I'm not confident I have my 4x4 box for the dryer in the correct position.

When mounting a 4x4 metal box such as the one in the photo below, am I correct in flushing the box with the face of the dimensional studs, then, applying a 5/8" mud-ring for the 5/8" drywall? Where is my drywall cutout, should it be the square outer edge of the mud-ring?

My desire would be to have a matching face plate such as the receptacle box next to it.
I don't think I properly understand how and when to use a mud-ring.

All advice is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a cover plate. This is how the receptacle would be mounted in an exposed work type of installation.

A mud ring would look like this (thanks to homedepot.com for the image):

[image: 2 gang mud ring]

The difference is that the mud ring simply holds the device in place; it does not count as a "cover" because it does not keep fingers and objects away from the wiring. You'd trim the drywall around the perimeter of the raised part of the mud ring and fill in between the metal and the drywall with mud (drywall compound) and tape if necessary. After mud and paint are finished a flat cover plate like the one on your nearby duplex receptacle goes on.

Comment: Greg thank you so much! I have several various "mud rings" and covers, the distinction between "cover" and "extender/mud ring" was not clicking with me until I read your explanation - thank you! So, as for the box location, flush to the face of the stud then an appropriate depth mud ring, hang and cut out drywall, install device and cover (which I have but was just dense!) Thank you!